# how to present a talk on work in preparation

Tags: graduate-school, etiquette, lab-meeting

I guess this is very common, to do a presentation to your lab. I wonder how I can cite in my slides that the presented work will be part of a future paper.

I remember to see in past presentations a footnote with " Author A & Author B (in preparation)", but I am not sure.

or I should forget all this and just present the work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the work corresponds to a paper submitted to a conference, I put in the slides "submitted to conference X". Otherwise, you can put "ongoing work with Author B". If you present the work in part of a seminar, you can put "Seminar of the department X".

But mainly, you don't *have to* put anything, especially if the slides are not put on the web or distributed. The only important point I would say, is to indicate if your work has been done with other people, in which case, you can write "Joint work with B".